# URL on SSL certificate is not the website I am on

Tags: ssl, proxy, pfsense

When I go to https://www.virgintrainseastcoast.com/ I get repeatedly get asked by Chrome to "Select a certificate". The certificate in the popup is usually either an Apple or Facebook URL.

Any ideas what is going on here?

We have installed a pfSense proxy and the user is going through a Cisco RV215W firewall router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website is using SSL Client certificates for authentication. The dialog box is asking you to specify which certificate you'd like to authenticate with.

Comment: So why since we changed the network infrastructure does this now come up. When I go to the same website on a completely different network, I dont get the prompt.

Comment: No idea. You'll need to talk with the people that run the website and network.